# Send command to iPhone under Mobile Device Managment

Tags: ios, mdm

Currently, our client's app is in the AppStore, but they want to distribute it to schools and universities. Also, they want the student when opens app first time would be already logged in.

There are tons of info on the internet but it's hard for me to compile it into something clear. As far as I understood first they should enroll in Apple School Manager and rise their own Mobile Device Management. Then devices should be registered on that server. After that server will be sending those commands [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/commands_and_queries). Is that correct?

Also what concerns silent login. The only way to implement it that comes into my mind is to at the app launch send request with some specific data(but what?) and if this is the device under Apple School Manager then return token.

P.S. I hope this is the correct place to ask this kind of question.